# Why does PHP parse the datestring "13.09.17" to today

Tags: php, date

Can someone explain the rationale why PHP parses the following string to the date of today?

```
php -r 'echo date("d-F-Y",strtotime("13.09.17"));'

21-September-2017
```

interpreted as a time without date?

Comment: Format as `d-F-Y H:i:s` and you might understand what PHP has interpreted here

Comment: you could use `php -r 'echo date("d-F-Y", \DateTime::createFromFormat("d.m.y", "13.09.17")->getTimestamp());'`;

Comment: @okante good approach, but using `getTimestamp()`  to use it in `date` is a bit suboptimal. Since you created a `\DateTime` object, you can format directly: `echo \DateTime::createFromFormat("d.m.y", "13.09.17")->format("d-F-Y");`

Comment: @AlexBlex, right :)

Answer (score 1):

Because it assumes dot`.` notation is for time, and the default date is today. See

```
php -r 'echo date("d-F-Y H:i:s",strtotime("13.09.17"));'
```

returns "21-September-2017 13:09:17".

If you replace dots with slashes, it will return expected date:

```
php -r 'echo date("d-F-Y",strtotime("13/09/17"));'
```

Comment: Dot notation is not always for time: `php -r 'echo date("d-F-Y H:i:s",strtotime("19.12.2015"));'`

Comment: @Janghou very true. I believe okante's approach to explicitly specify format is the best one.

Answer (score 1):

`strtotime` always has problems with dmy formatted dates, even when the day is >12 and they're not ambiguous with mdy. Changing the separator leads to some interesting results:

```
$format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
date($format, strtotime("13/09/17")); // 1970-01-01 00:00:00
date($format, strtotime("13-09-17")); // 2013-09-17 00:00:00
date($format, strtotime("13.09.17")); // 2017-09-21 13:09:17
```

For each of these cases, you end up with a different datetime, but none of them is the one you're actually referring to (September 13th, 2017). The first isn't considered valid, since it thinks you're referring to a 13th month. The second is interpreted as year-month-day. The third is interpreted as a time, and so defaults to that time on the current date.

For best results, and where you're in control of the format the string is using, you should use `DateTime::createFromFormat`

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("d.m.y", "13.09.17");
$date->format($format); // 2017-09-13 10:56:25
```

That way, you can avoid any ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
php -r 'echo date("jS F, Y",strtotime("13-09-17"));'
```

For more detail, take a look at the examples from 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Hope that will help you